# New registered user not receiving privileges

Tags: support, reputation

A new user recently registered his account, but his rep score is still below the 101 "automatic" rep score of a registered user, and (as a result) he does not have privileges like commenting on questions and answers.

Is there just a delay? Is something not working? did he not actually succeed in registering his account?

Comment: the 100 extra points are for associating one's account with a separate stackexchange site where he already has 200 points. ie if we trust that you aren't a troll there, then we trust you aren't a troll here.

Comment: @DoubleAA, huh? That doesn't make any sense. How can a new user on any SE site then get recognized if he is dependent on another SE site for verification? Is this a new policy? Because I am nearly 100% certain (correct me if I'm wrong, but I really don't think so) that new users used to get a 101 rep score when they registered their accounts the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/166155) asking why the OP got the 100 points. The answer:

> Congratulations! One of your linked accounts has reached 200 reputation points, and as a result, all associated accounts are given a 100 point bonus.
>
> The bonus is awarded because you have proven that you know your way around the basic features of any Stack Exchange website, and with those 100 extra points you can now comment, vote, flag and create bounties on all SE sites.

Your first reputation points have to come the old-fashioned way (asking and answering). But once you know what's going on on an SE site (and we know you're not a troll) then you get a helpful initial boost for other SE sites.

This has been the case since around April 2011 ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90712/166155)).

Comment: Interesting. Shows what I know. I've been around too long, I guess.